# Get Response headers in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, rest, meteor, frontend, response-headers

## Situation

From my Meteor.js website I'm calling my own REST service. Here's a code sample from my server side

```
function (question) {   
    var r = Async.runSync(function (done) {
        HTTP.get(URL, {
            params: {q: question}, headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
            }
        }, function (err, result) {
            done(err, result);
        });
    });
    if (r.err) {
        console.log("Failed to smartSearch ... ", r.err);
        return null;
    } else if (r.result.content) {
        console.log("Success ... ");
        return JSON.parse(r.result.content);
    }
}
```

This works great but there is also some crucial information in the **response headers** which I'm unable to find.

## What I've tried so far

- I viewed everything within **r.result.content**, but this only contains my request headers.
- I've installed https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/headers and tried everything the site said.

But still not seeing my response headers.

## Additional Information

I'm fairly new to Meteor.js so I don't really have an idea what I might be doing wrong but getting response headers doesn't see like a strange thing to me.

Comment: which router are you using for your rest service?

Comment: I think it's Iron-router: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router (I'm not the one who setup the project) where can I validate this?

Comment: in .meteor folder, you'll find a file called packages. you can see all the packages you are using.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, I don't recall using the iron-router for my server side, but as you can see in my code snippet I do use the http package. Here's a printscreen with all the installed packages: http://prntscr.com/bsperx

Comment: You can use the sync syntax on the server: `let response = HTTP.get(...)`. The `response` object should have a `headers` property which includes the response headers.

Comment: @MasterAM You're right, but it seems he combines the request and response headers which made it a little unclear. thanks

Comment: This should not be the case. Are you sure about it?

Comment: @MasterAM, Ah this was also my bad. some of the headers from my request are just returned in the response headers as well!

Comment: Great. I have posted an answer to mark this one solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to wrap the request as an async call, as it already is.

You can use a `try..catch` block to handle both successful and failed requests.

```js
try {
  var result = HTTP.get(...);
  var responseHeaders = result.headers;
} catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

If the response headers indicate `JSON` response, it will be parsed and available as `result.data`. The response will be available as a string in `result.content`.

More details are available in the [HTTP package API docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html).